# Nested List refresh

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

Any one knows how to refresh a nested list?

I am creating a list. On tap of an item it loads a nested list. if i traverse in a nested list and then tap to another item and come back to the prev item, its still stuck in the place where it was last left.

I tried using

```
Ext.getCmp('nestedList').refresh();
```

but thet doesn seem to work.

Below is my code for the nested list panel.

```
Ext.define("InfoImage.view.nestedList", {
    extend:'Ext.NestedList',
    xtype:'nestedList',
    id:'nestedList',

    config:{
        fullscreen:'true',
        title:'Work Items Task 1',
       // ui:'normal',
        xtype:'nestedList',
        displayField : 'text',
        store:'nestedListStore',
        style: {
            'background-color': 'rgba(0,140,153,0.1)'
        }

    } 
});
```

and the code for loading the nested list is:

```
showListDetail : function(view, index, item, record) {
                        var rec = view.getStore().getAt(index);
                        // Ext.getStore('workItemStore').add({Task: '7'
                        // },{Server: 'mobcomp1'});
                        if (index == 0) {

                            this.getDocPanel().animateActiveItem(
                                    this.getNestedPanel(), {
                                        type : 'slide',
                                        direction : 'up',
                                        duration : 250
                                    });
                            Ext.getCmp('nestedList').reload();

                        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly refresh a `nestedlist`. There's no `refresh()` or `reload()` method for it.

All you need to do is `load` the store which is used for your `nestedlist` using it's configured `proxy`.

```
 this.store.setProxy({
    // proxy configurations ...
    // ......
    // ......
 });
 this.store.load();
```

Comment: By "store" do u mean my nestedlistStore name or just "store" itself. I tried the code n my controllers just before loading the nested lists, but it dint seem to work.

Comment: I mean, the nestedListStore .. something like this .. `Ext.getCmp('nestedListId').getStore().load();` ..